# How do I show a requirement for OS 5 in my Blackberry widgets?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-widgets

I am developing a Blackberry widget application, which I know requires OS 5.

Now, I'm using OTA installation, but when a user without OS 5 loads the .jad file, they get an exception like:

```
This application requires the following modules which are not installed:
net_rim_bb_browser_field2_api
net_rim_bb_web_jse_api
net_rim_networkap
```

I want to be able to stop users from installing this if it won't work on their phones, and optionally display some sort of message asking them to upgrade.

Surely other people have encountered this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this with OTA installation you will have to have your HTTP server pull the OS related data out of the request meta-data and respond with the appropriate page, or provide instructions on a page that contains the link to the JAD file. As far as I have been able to determine there isn't a way to be OS specific in the JAD file for OTA. It would be nice if someone could prove me wrong in this.

Comment: I think you're correct, Richard.  For our app, we check the user-agent and x-wap-profile headers to determine the device model and OS version, which then determines which JAD file to serve the device (or error page if not supported).